# ansible docker_compose network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, ansible-template

I am trying to execute the following task:

```
- docker_compose:
    project_name: traefik
    definition:
      traefik:
        image: "traefik:v2.2"
        container_name: "traefik"
        restart: always
        networks:
          - edge-router
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
          # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
          - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
          - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
          - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
          - ./routing:/etc/routing/
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

in ansible and it shows me:

```
Configuration error - The Compose file '/tmp/ansibley0n2s1ya/docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:\nUnsupported config option for traefik: 'networks'"
```

The `docker-compose.yaml` file works:

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.2"
    container_name: "traefik"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - edge-router
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
      - ./routing:/etc/routing/
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

What should I use instead of networks option in ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`networks` is available in compose versions 2 and 3.  Unless explicitly specified, ansible's `docker-compose` module defaults to version `1`.

Update your definition to include the `version`

```
- docker_compose:
    project_name: traefik
    definition:
      version: '2'
      traefik:
        image: "traefik:v2.2"
        container_name: "traefik"
        restart: always
        networks:
...
```